# How to load cached Image in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-storage

Actually, I have a website which is taking time to retrieve the User Profile Picture from the Firebase server and I want to know If there is any way by which I can cache the image and use it next time the website is loaded.

The code I am using for retrieving the image from firebase is-

```
firebase.database().ref("/" + uid).child('userId').on('value', function(snapshot){

var storeTheUserId=snapshot.val();
var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref();
var setTheChild=storageRef.child(storeTheUserId + '.png')

setTheChild.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){

document.getElementById('userProfilePicture').src=url;

});

});
```

I just want to use the cached Image and use it next time when the website is loaded.

Comment: You can set header in firebase.json file, https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

Comment: `"source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "max-age=7200"
    } ]`

Comment: Hey, thanks man, for your support

Comment: You can explicitly cache the image in CacheStorage, but this may be more than you need (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage)

Comment: @KapilKaushik Welcome :)